# SoftwareSerial runs out of "text" space on ATtiny

Tags: softwareserial, attiny, memory

I have an ATtiny and am trying to send a very large byte array stored in a separate `.h` file over SoftwareSerial:

```
for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++) {
    softSerial.println(myList[i]);
}
```

I imagine it will very slow, which is fine, but I'm getting a cryptic error when compiling:

```
Firmware.ino.elf section `.data' will not fit in region `text'
```

It seems that this is due to the `println()` command running out of memory for some reason – if I comment out the `println()` command everything works fine. How to fix this?

Comment: perhaps, if you remove the line where you use the array, compiler optimizes the code removing the not used array

Comment: how big is the .h file?

Comment: @Juraj – not sure I understand? The array is what's getting sent over serial, which is the point of my program.

Comment: @ChadG – it's about 140kb.

Comment: is it used elsewhere in the sketch or only in the commented println?

Comment: @Juraj – it isn't used anywhere else, just printed over serial.

Comment: how do you expect it to fit in 8KB worth of program space( thats what the ATtiny85 has)

Comment: if something is not used, the compiler doesn't put it into final code. it is why you do not get the warning if you comment the print of the array

Comment: The uno only has 32KB but the Mega does have 256KB. Remember though, there is a difference between where stuff is stored, program space and ram. There is still not enought ram on any of these devices to handle that large of a byte array.

Comment: have a look here     https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory

Comment: Is there a way to compress this data? Any repeating sections? Only a limited amount of different characters? ASCII only needs 7 bit!

Comment: How big is the array? In other words, what is the data declaration for `myList`? Is it, for example: `int myList [35000];`

Comment: @NickGammon – the version I had was `143186` bytes long. I'm now seeing there's no way that takes up less that 141k in the Arduino's memory though, right?

Comment: I would prefer if you answered my question. How is the array declared? I don't care how big the file is, it might be full of comments.

Comment: However unless the file is **99%** comments then it is unlikely that it will fit into 8KB of program memory. Also the compiler generates code to copy variables with initial values from program memory into RAM, unless you declared it as `PROGMEM`, and it is even less likely your data will fit into your 512 bytes of RAM. See [my page about that](http://www.gammon.com.au/progmem).

Comment: @NickGammon – here's the first little bit: `const unsigned char dna[] = { 0x37, 0x7a, 0xbc, 0xaf... };` I think I was confused since it compiled with no issues, until I actually needed to use the array.

Comment: OK, you are letting the compiler determine the size. Do you know offhand how many bytes are in this array? (eg. 0x37 is one byte). You could conceivably put that array onto a larger machine (eg. use gcc on your PC) and then use `sizeof` to find how big the array is.

Comment: Yes, it compiled with no issues, particularly if you didn't reference the array, so that the linker can then strip the array from the final hex file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sketch doesn't fit into program memory of the ATtiny. If you comment out the `println` of the array, the compiler evaluates that the array is not used and doesn't attach it to the program. Then the program fits into memory.

**EDIT**
Chad suggests some good alternatives below, if you need to store more data than flash or `PROGMEM` will allow.

Comment: Thanks – 140kb is the ascii representation of all those bytes. I had read that it gets crunched down to binary on compile, and was trying to see if it fit. Didn't realize the array would be ignored until invoked by `println()`.

Answer (score 3):

There is not enough room in program memory for 140KB. ATiny only has 8KB for the whole program. So there is no way to fix this with your current hardware.

Options-

add a storage device (SD card, sram module, others....) where you can store the data, and then read it in small chunks and send it out

possibly use a arduino mega. It has 256KB of program space. you will still have to make sure you are not trying to store the whole byte array in an array since that would get stored in sram (which there is still only 8KB) but it could again to written in chunks to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The ATTiny only has a limited amount of RAM. A lot less that flash-memory.

Using a normal array, the entire contents of the array are placed into RAM (during initialization). Which is very limited.

I'd suggest, looking into [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/). This is a way to read the data directly from the flash-memory.

Comment: Looking at the comments, this will still not fit the 140kb you want. But the ATTiny85 only has 512 bytes of RAM, but a whole 8KB of Flash/Program memory.